# How to Unhide tagged detail disclosure button depending on which button was pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my view controller, I have 6 buttons (IBAction buttonDown(tagged 0 - 5)), and their corresponding detail disclosure buttons (UIButton* disclosureButton(tagged 0 - 5)).

I was wondering if there was a way to hide all the detail disclosure buttons by default, but if the button tagged 0 is pressed, the detail disclosure button tagged 0 is shown etc.

Here is the code I currently have in my ViewController.m file

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _stopSound.hidden = YES;

}

- (IBAction)stopSound:(UIButton *)sender {
    P11AppDelegate* app = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [app.host stop];

    _stopSound.hidden = YES;

}

- (IBAction)buttonDown:(UIButton *)sender
{
    P11AppDelegate* app = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [app.host start];
    [app playSound:sender.tag];

    _stopSound.hidden = NO;
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{    
    UIButton* disclosureButton = sender;
    P11AppDelegate* app = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    app.editIndex = disclosureButton.tag;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with the following code in viewDidLoad:

```
   //hide info buttons
for (int i = 0; i < self.infoButtons.count; i++)
{
    UIButton* button = [self.infoButtons objectAtIndexedSubscript:i];
    button.hidden = YES;

}
```

and when the button is pressed:

```
//info button reappears when sound button is pressed
for (int i = 0; i < self.infoButtons.count; i++)
{
    UIButton* button = self.infoButtons[i];
    button.hidden = button.tag == sender.tag ? NO : YES;
}
```